# AttributeERROR : module'tensorflow.keras.applicationsas no attribute efficientnet_v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, efficientnet

When i try to run the efficientNetv2 model
I got this erreur [Error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpe8K.jpg)

`AttributeError: module'tensorflow.keras.applications ' has no attribute 'efficientnet_v2'`

Tensorflow version : tensorflow-gpu:2.6

Answer (score 1):

The import is incorrect, you need to update it, it might have worked in older Keras versions,but the internal per-network modules inside `keras.applications` are not exposed anymore, so your correct import would be:

```
keras.applications.EfficientNetV2S
```

Or if you use `tf.keras`:

```
tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetV2S
```

For future reference, always check the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/applications/), for EfficientNetV2S the link is [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet_v2/#efficientnetv2s-function).

Answer (score 0):

install efficientnet in you env
!pip install keras-efficientnet

then you can import model as

import efficientnet.tfkeras as efc

done...
you can use prefix 'efc' for B0-B7

Comment: This does not seem to address the issue addressed by the question